# Trying to select all rows in this column with a certain value, and failing

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I am new to writing raw SQL queries so forgive me for this being *easy* to solve. The database is Postgres.

I have a table similar to:

```
taskId     providerName     lastScan     ignore
==================================================
  3        rentCanada        null        false
  4        rentCanada        today       false
  5        rentSeeker        null        false
```

My goal is to write a query that selects all rows where providerName is `rentCanada` or `rentSeeker` and the lastScan value is either null or not null. I wish to count the values for each query.

I tried:

`SELECT COUNT(providerName) FROM public."Tasks" HAVING Tasks.providerName=rentSeeker`

Gives

```
ERROR:  column "providername" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(providerName) FROM public."Tasks" HAVING Tasks....
                     ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "Tasks.providerName".
```

So I tried to add:

`SELECT COUNT("Tasks.providerName") FROM public."Tasks" HAVING Tasks.providerName=rentSeeker`

Gives `ERROR:  column "Tasks.providerName" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT("Tasks.providerName") FROM public."Tasks" HAVIN...`

Ok so maybe without the quotations: `SELECT COUNT(Tasks.providerName) FROM public."Tasks" HAVING Tasks.providerName=rentSeeker`

Nope, `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tasks" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(Tasks.providerName) FROM public."Tasks" HAVING ...`

I found [PostgreSQL COUNT() function overview](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-count-function/) and tried: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public."Tasks" HAVING providerName=rentSeeker`

Gives

```
ERROR:  column "providername" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public."Tasks" HAVING providerName=rent...
                                                   ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "Tasks.providerName".
```

I don't understand why so many of the queries I've tried that look like they should work, do not work. As far as I can tell I should be getting results for `SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE lastScan = null` but it gives

```
ERROR:  relation "tasks" does not exist
LINE 1:  SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE lastScan = null
                       ^
```

A video I'm watching says `SELECT * FROM public.customers WHERE id = 3` so one would think that `SELECT * FROM public.Tasks WHERE taskId = 3` would run for me since my table is called `Tasks` and the id field is called `taskId`. But no. It doesn't run.

Comment: `"providerName"`

Comment: `SELECT "providerName" FROM public."Tasks" ` worked! Progress. So did `SELECT "providerName", "lastScan" FROM public."Tasks" WHERE "lastScan" IS NULL`. Thank you!